# Reference classes in Android APK

Tags: java, android, apk, robotium

I'm working on test automation for an android app. We only receive an apk to test. The app uses some custom views. I need to reference the apk like a library so I can reference the classes in apk. How do I do it in eclipse?

I tried adding it to build path like a normal jar. Package explorer can see all the assets but none of the classes.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I do it in eclipse?

You don't. It is not possible. Demand the source code for the project you are testing.

Comment: Shame, I was afraid that will be the answer. I guess that leaves reflection.

Comment: @Rad: I doubt that will work, either. If all you have is the APK, you cannot manipulate it from your own code. Even instrumentation requires you to have signed the APK with your own signing key. You can use the test monkey, but probably not much more.